# How to define a suitable error criterian for a neural network model prediction?

Tags: prediction, error

I have trained a model that predicts location of two objects. As output, I have X1, X2. I am looking to define a suitable error criterion so that it shows understandable mean of error for model. Could somebody please tell me if this model is true or no?
(suppose x1, x2, y1, y2 are real values and predicted ones respectively and N is number of data included in test dataset)
error = (1/n)*sqrt(\sigma((y1-x1)^2 + (y2-x2)^2))

Comment: What is sigma? Why do you have a factor of 1/n? Your expression looks like a scaled squared error term.

Comment: @MONODA43 thanks for reply, from sigma, i mean summation. (1/n) because there are n data and i thought if it is true for mean error?